# Jquery Validation restrict characters on live?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to block or restrict special characters from input fields with [jquery-validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org)?

For example, I would like to only authorize those characters `[0-9\/]*`.

I've read the whole documentation but I haven't found anything. So instead I've to write special codes for this which is not a good choice for the code.

I've seen that other javascript plugin validation can do that like [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#custom) by using a `requirementType`. But I don't really want to change the plugin to another cause I already know how to use it now.

Comment: Not sure what restrictions you have with regard to browser compatibility... But this MDN entry might be of some use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern. For info on where this feature is supported - see here - http://caniuse.com/#search=pattern

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery validation, you can use this method (http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod) to add a validator that uses JavScript regex matching to return true or false if the input matches your pattern. This is a very easy way to integrate with the library you're using.

If you want to literally prevent the user from typing characters other than those, you need to attach an event handler to the inputs and block those characters on the `keyDown` event.

Either way, the matching logic is the same.

Comment: Ok but if I do it this way, it's like I've two validation endpoints. I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You still only have 1 validation endpoint. The validator will only run when the field value changes. The input restriction will stop the value from changing if the character is not allowed. Does this make sense or am I missing something about how you need it to work?